# mysql grant privileges over ssh

Tags: mysql, ssh

the command:

```
ssh xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx \"mysql -u root -password \\\"grant all privileges on rcf_275d315.* to rfc_user@localhost identified by \'W27j453frxrff23\'\\\"\"
```

gives me an error:

```
bash: mysql -u root -p97yf2beiru3trf289 "grant all privileges on rcf_275d315.* to rfc_user@localhost identified by 'W27j453frxrff23'": command not found
```

when i copy the string returned by bash, end run locally it works. Also works, when pasted on the remote serve.

For some reason it doesn't work over ssh, and returns error:

```
mysql -u root -p97yf2beiru3trf289 "grant all privileges on rcf_275d315.* to rfc_user@localhost identified by 'W27j453frxrff23'": command not found
```

---

### UPDATE:

i tried few variations, without success:

```
ssh xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx \"mysql -u root -pBOY8o7ubio87gubip7 \\\"grant all privileges on rfc_275d315.* to rfc_user identified by \'KUG34dY976fyvc768g\'\\\"\"
```

result:

```
bash: mysql -u root -pBOY8o7ubio87gubip7 "grant all privileges on rfc_275d315.* to rfc_user identified by 'KUG34dY976fyvc768g'": command not found


ssh xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx \"mysql -u root -pBOY8o7ubio87gubip7 \\"grant all privileges on rfc_275d315.* to rfc_user identified by \'KUG34dY976fyvc768g\'\\"\"
```

result:

```
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file


ssh xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx mysql -u root -pBOY8o7ubio87gubip7 \\"grant all privileges on rfc_275d315.* to rfc_user identified by \'KUG34dY976fyvc768g\'\\"
```

result:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.66, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1
Copyright (c) 2000, 2012, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
```

owners.

```
Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]
  -?, --help          Display this help and exit.



ssh xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx mysql -u root -pBOY8o7ubio87gubip7 \\\"grant all privileges on rfc_275d315.* to rfc_user identified by \'KUG34dY976fyvc768g\'\\\"
```

result:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.66, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1
Copyright (c) 2000, 2012, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
```

owners.

```
Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]
  -?, --help          Display this help and exit.
```

still, don't where the problem is. Thanks for any help.

UPDATE:
when echo saved to file:
ssh xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "echo mysql -u root -piugiu -e \\"grant all privileges on rfc_275d315.* to rfc_user identified by \'in76bn6bgb876n\'\\" > rfc/echo.txt"

i get this in file:
mysql -u root -piugiu -e "grant all privileges on rfc_275d315.* to rfc_user identified by 'in76bn6bgb876n'"

which is proper command, and when copied and pasted to command line on remote server it works, as it should.

when echo is removed:
ssh xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "mysql -u root -piugiu -e \\"grant all privileges on rfc_275d315.* to rfc_user identified by \'in76bn6bgb876n\'\\" > rfc/echo.txt"

the text file contain info about usage of mysql:
Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]
  -?, --help          Display this help and exit.

Comment: login to ssh... then type `mysql`... once u r inside mysql, fire query `grant .....`. Also **never share your actual passwords**

Comment: i'd like to do it without going inside mysql. This should be executed from the script.
I'm able to create, and restore db this way. All I need is to grant privileges for him on that db.

Comment: btw, these are not the real passwords :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ssh xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 'mysql -u root -pBOY8o7ubio87gubip7 -e "grant all privileges on rfc_275d315.* to rfc_user@localhost identified by '\''KUG34dY976fyvc768g'\''" yourdatabase'
```

Should be working. You forgot the `-e` in the MySQL client parameters which allows you to pass a statement

**EDIT 1:**

fixed quoting

In bash you can differ two ways of quoting (just like in many other languages)

**1. Weak quoting: double quotes**

e.g. `echo "$PATH"`

> In a weak-quoted string there is no interpretion of
>
> - spaces as word-separators
> - pathname expansion
> - process substitution
> - single-quotes to introduce strong-quoting
> - characters for pattern matching

Otherwise parameter expansion is done:

`ls -l "*"`

not be interpreted, will pass `*` literally and will cause an error unless you have a file called `*`

`echo "Your PATH is: $PATH"`

Will work as expected. `$PATH` is interpreted

**2. Strong quoting: single quotes**

Within single quotes you get no interpretation at all. All characters within single quotes are treated as text.

If you have to use the single quote within a single-quoted text, simply escaping isn't enough. You have to concat like this:

`QUERY='SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE col1 = '` `\'` `'value1'` `\'`

source: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting

Comment: bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: tested and fixed the answer

Comment: didi you tested granting privileges over ssh?

based, on what you write, this:

ssh xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx mysql -u root -pn76tgn6786g -e 'grant all privileges on rfx_275d315.* to rfx_user@localhost identified by '\''bg867bngb87b6gn'\'''

gives me this:
Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]

Comment: assuming, here is what i need: 

'mysql -u .... 'grand all... identified by 'password' ' '

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to quote the command you send to `ssh`. Remove your outermost layer of quoting around your `mysql` command and it should work fine.